# Need .stf example

Tags: translation, customlabel, translation-workbench

Got stuck with importing translations of custom labels. I'm using translation workbench and its import file page. Base file for my import is one exported by Salesforce workbench with some edits. Already looked through various documentation articles regarding format but still couldn't find working solution.

Could anyone please provide an *example* of import .stf file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double check you're using tabs and not spaces and that the file is really saved as UTF-8 (you can use Notepad++ for example to check & force it).

Eh, the StackExchange's editor converts tabs to spaces. Check out http://pastebin.com/FEK7epN2 (raw data)

```
# Language: German
Language code: de
Type: Bilingual

------------------TRANSLATED-------------------

# KEY   LABEL   TRANSLATION OUT OF DATE

ButtonOrLink.Event.New_Event    New Event   Neues Ereignis  -
ButtonOrLink.Opportunity.Add_Line_Items Add Line Items  Artikelanlage   -
# eyescream: skipped some
CustomLabel.PKB2_All_Fields_Required    All fields are required.    Alle Felder sind obligatorisch. -
CustomLabel.PKB2_Answers_Might_Help These answers might help immediately    Diese Antworten könnten vielleicht helfen   -
CustomLabel.PKB2_Back_To_Search_Page    Back to search page Zurück zur Suchseite    -
CustomLabel.PKB2_Cancel Cancel  Abbrechen   -
# eyescream: skipped some
CustomLabel.SC_Case_Information Case Information    Beschreibungsinformationen  -
CustomLabel.SC_New_Case New Case    Neuer Kundenvorgang -
CustomLabel.SC_New_Find_Contact New / Find Contact  Neuer Kontakt / Kontakt suchen  -
CustomLabel.SC_Save_New Save & New  Speichern & Neu -

------------------UNTRANSLATED-----------------

# KEY   LABEL

ButtonOrLink.Order__c.Mass_edit Edit
ButtonOrLink.Order__c.Printable_view    Printable view!
ButtonOrLink.Order__c.Quick_Email   Quick Email
```

Not sure if you see it, I've "translated" one of last labels to "Printable view!" and imported whole file back to SF (I didn't zip anything, uploaded this one language directly):

[image]

So it ignores lines where the translation is blank or identical to your master language.

Comment: Nope, it still doesn't work. It says [No data to import.]

Comment: Well, it won't work if you don't have custom labels that match "my" names. Hard to say more... can you post bits of your file maybe?

Comment: Yeah did it! The problem was that default org language and language the file was exported with were different. And it seems that both translated and untranslated sections are required, being at least empty.

Answer (score 0):

Additions for [eyescream](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/799/eyescream)' great answer:

At the file header, The Language code and Language **Should be into YOUR LANGUAGE**

I translated Chinese for example, I should use:

```
语言代码： zh_CN
类型： 来源
```

to make sure the `stf` file has proper file header that Salesforce can understand.

Answer (score 0):

Importing translations of custom labels can indeed be challenging, and it's important to ensure that the STF file is in the correct format. Here's an example of an import STF file for custom labels:

#Language: Chinese (Simplified)

Language code: zh_CN

Type: Bilingual

Translation type: Metadata

------------------OUTDATED AND UNTRANSLATED-----------------

#KEY LABEL

CustomLabel.MFU_DeleteFileConfirm 您确定要删除文件吗？
CustomLabel.MFU_SelectValidRecord 请选择有效记录。

If you're still facing issues with the import, it's worth considering a more streamlined solution. You can use the AppExchange app 'Quick Update Translations' to simplify the translation process for custom labels and other Salesforce elements. This app eliminates the need for manual STF file creation and provides a user-friendly interface for managing translations.

You can find more information about the app and access it through this AppExchange Link: https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=fa9afbfe-74ff-4027-ac32-2cdfd58184d3

Disclaimer: I work at Satrang Technologies, the publisher of the 'Quick Update Translations' AppExchange App.

Best Regards,

Nikita